# Customized theme for every logged in user

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have dotnet 3.5 webforms application with entity framework used.
I am not able to figure out how to give a customized theme for every logged in user, just like twitter users have mainly the UI change(logo, color,etc)

Please help.

Comment: suppose if you have 2000 users then do you mean you want to create 2000 typs of `css` ? 
or you want to load alternate `css`  when user login to their account ?
Can you please give some more clarity on this ?

Comment: @Sunil: thanks for raising this question, yes every user have there specific    customized theme which will be activated, by the admin of the site,the admin is responsible to set the theme for the user and the theme will be activated once the user is logged in.

Answer (score 1):

According to my view Creating a different-different `CSS/Theme` is not possible here. Because we are going to deal with thousand of users.

Creating multiple `themes` or `CSS` can be work if we create only 4-5 `themes/css`.

I have a solution for you, by you can create many different `CSS`. 
You have to create a column in your USER Table like:

`UserTheme` OR `UserStyle` `varchar(max)`

and when you are going to register your user you can Create dynamic `CSS` on the Basis of Primary Key and change the `CSS` attributes like below:

```
body
{
color: #cc0033;
background-color: #996666;
}
```

here you can create your Unique Color codes or Background color codes
Like below:

```
color: #cc0033;
```

**BreakDown:**

`#(Constant)
cc(it can be first digit of first name and Second name)
00(it can be any random value)
33(it can be your user primary key)`

Now you can Create your Unique Color codes and background-color codes for the `body` and save it to your table column which we have to create before sec ago.

and when you are going to create your Logged in user Dashboard you have to render your custom `css` at your master page code behind like below:

**C# Code:**

```
<style type="text/css" runat="server" id="htmlCss"></style>

var css = @"
body
{
  background-color:#b0c4de;
}"; // Your Server CSS goes here
htmlCss.InnerHtml = css;
```

Hope this logic will helps you.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the logic. I am going to apply this logic. if i have any query i will ask surely.

Comment: Sure kindly mark the answer if it helps you